# Filling an empty, typed object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to loop over an array in order to fill an object with typescript.

In vanilla JS I would do this like so:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b'];

var obj = {};
arr.map((v,ii) => {obj[v] = ii});

console.log(obj); // => obj = {a: 0, b: 1}
```

Now in typescript I want to do something similar but have the object be typed:

```
interface IObj = {a: number; b: number}

var arr = ['a', 'b'];

var obj:IObj = {};
arr.map((v,ii) => {obj[v] = ii}});
```

This will spit out an error because `{}` does not have type `IObj`.

I understand that I could declare the type of `obj` to be `IObj | {}` but other parts of my code are expecting `IObj` only.

Comment: You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): `var obj:IObj = <IObj>{}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `{}` is an object of the `IObj` type:

```
var obj: IObj = <IObj>{}
```

This basically tells the compiler *"Trust me, I know what I'm doing."*.
It is a powerful feature and it comes with responsibilities. Use it responsibly.

Comment: I see. Would this be considered a place where it would be [safe](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) to use assertions? Also, on the same page of that [ebook](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) the author suggests that the compiler will take care of `var obj:IObj = {}` without any troubles. Is this information perhaps out of date?

Comment: Regarding the second question, what do you trust more, your compiler or some random tutorial?

Comment: Haha...fair point. I was wondering if it might be a configuration difference.